# Using jfrog artifactory OSS with basic API calls

Tags: package-management, open-source, artifactory

I am using the OSS version over JFrog, but the basic api calls are failing for me.

`curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -umarco:cmVmdGtuOjAxOjAwMDAwMDAwMDA6eElCQ21ZYTA5M1ZsVzU2TWFxUG5oWVBKRnYz \ http://localhost/artifactory/api/repositories/test -d "{}"`

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "This REST API is available only in Artifactory Pro (see: jfrog.com/artifactory/features). If you are already running Artifactory Pro please make sure your server is activated with a valid license key.\n"
  } ]
```

The official documentation https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/create-repository does not mention on any restrictions.

It sees that all POST and PUT calls are filtered in the OSS version.
What are others doing to get around these limitations? Is there a different community edition that allows API calls? Is there a better alternative to JFrog.
It seems that the OSS version is severely restricted.

Regards,

Marco

Comment: Take a look on Nexus repository: https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-repository